# Query Two Databases at once using Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have function called **getData($Books, $Users, $InputID);** that receives two database connections and User ID.

On the User Database, I have a table called **Users**

```
-----------------
UserID | UserName
-----------------
```

On the Books Database, I have a table called **Books**

```
 ------------------------------
 BookID | BookName | BookUserID
 ------------------------------
```

What I want to do is to write **ONE** query that will:

Select the the User on the **Users** table with **UserID = $InputID**, and also select the book on **Books** Table where **BookUserID = $InputID**;

This must be done using a Prepared Statement..
This is what i have tried.

```
function getData($Books, $Users, $InputID){

$fetch_results = prepare('SELECT * from UsersDB.Users U LEFT JOIN BooksDB.Books B ON B.BookUserID = U.UserID   Where UserID = :InputID');

$fetch_results->execute(array(':userID' => $InputID));
return $Data;
```

}

Comment: What is stopping you from doing that? Hint: DB1.table_x .... DB2.table_y

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Selecting from both the databases with one query using a prepared statement.

Comment: @WebArtisan Yes, I have tried some queries with no luck.

Comment: Then show us your try.

Comment: @WebArtisan I have edited the question with what i tried.

Comment: and what happened when you tried? What error / problem occurred? PDO should have either thrown an error or returned `false` from the prepare() and/or execute() calls. I would guess the issue is because your parameter names don't match - in the execute statement you specify `:userID` but in the SQL you specify `:InputID` - make your mind up what you are calling the parameter.

Comment: @ADyson PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function prepare() in C:\projects\smartviewvisiotech\track\php\functions.php on line 48

Comment: well, did you define a function called "prepare()" in your code? if not, then that's why it's "undefined". The error message is simple enough. I would guess you intended to call the "prepare" method of your database library instead? are you using PDO, or mysqli? Have you created a database connection object? This is pretty basic stuff...did you take a tutorial about prepared statements? Did you think to google your error message?

Comment: But, can you help you can see whats wrong.

Comment: I've just told you exactly what's wrong. Read my comment again. You need to call the "prepare" function of your database connection object e.g. `$conn->prepare(`..etc. (replace $conn with whatever you called your connection variable). If you don't understand what I mean then _take a tutorial_ and _read the PHP documentation_ because this is really the most basic bit of using prepared statements. What your code is doing right now is trying to call a global function called "prepare()" which, obviously, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your both DB(UserDb, BooksDB) on same server then query will be like.

```
SELECT u.UserName, b.BookName
FROM UserDB.dbo.Users u
     INNER JOIN BooksDB.dbo.Books b 
     ON b.UserId = b.BookUserId
WHERE u.UserId = $InputID
      OR BookUserID = $InputID;
```

If your both DB(UserDB, BooksDB) on different server then.
First you need to create link for other server then fire the following like query with link name, Let your link Name is LinkServer2 and you are firing query from server1.UserDB. Make sure to use fully qualified name for linked server.

```
SELECT u.UserName, b.BookName
FROM UserDB.dbo.Users u
     INNER JOIN LinkServer2.BooksDB.dbo.Books b 
     ON b.UserId = b.BookUserId
WHERE u.UserId = $InputID
      OR BookUserID = $InputID;
```

if you want to use LEFT JOIN and retrieve all number of columns(SELECT *) then you can do it no problem.